# Proper time to close questions

Tags: discussion

Shouldn't the proper time to close questions be: before they've received answers? This one sat open for four days before being closed:

[Any other compound words with opposite meanings like "bittersweet"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/424701/any-other-compound-words-with-opposite-meanings-like-bittersweet/425144#425144)

May I also point out that down voting an answer before placing the question on hold, is an abuse of privilege.

Comment: Everyone’s on a different schedule, and it takes a consensus of 5 regular users (ie rep > 3k) to close a question, so there is no way to organize, mandate, or enforce a particular deadline for closure. People close-vote questions they deem close-worthy the first time they see a question, which could be a week or more after its posted. Whether a Q is answered or not has no bearing on whether the Q is on- or -off-topic. Extremely rarely an absolutely stellar answer can rescue a poor question, but that’s the exception, not the rule.

Comment: In re downvoting answers: no one knows why your answer was downvoted except the person who downvoted. It may or may not be one of the close voters. It may be because they disagreed with your answer. It may be because they want to discourage posting answers to off-topic questions (this is a contentious but not abusive practice). But in the end, voting is an earned privilege and the purpose of voting is to spend it in the way one sees fit. So there’s no use cavilling about it. We all get downvotes, and have to live with them.

Answer (score 7):

If questions should not be closed once they have received answers, then the system would enforce that and not permit it. Because it does not, answers are irrelevant to whether a question should be closed or not.

---

In this case, the question is asking for examples — as evidenced by the answers received. List questions are "too broad": there are too many possible answers, all equally valid and not easily chosen between when accepting an answer.

While it is *preferable* that answerers are spared the trouble they take in answering an off-topic question, it's not possible to maintain a constant vigilance and it may take even months or years. It is better that answerers recognise that a question is too broad and not bother answering.

A rather better course of action, if it's possible, is to edit the question to remove any list-request element and leave a question which is on topic. I don't believe that's possible here, although [it can be](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/425129/revisions) — but even then it may not be enough.

Voting is also unrelated to placing a question on hold: votes may be cast at any time, immediately after the answer is placed, after years, or at any point in between. Now that you have highlighted your answer here, it may garner further votes (up or down).

Comment: So you can still vote on answers already given on a closed question, just not provide any more answers. My misunderstanding, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

That would be *preferable*, since the main reason to close questions is to preempt useless attempts to answer them, but there are vague reasons that questions might accrue answers before they are closed. Some people do not know which questions should be closed, other people do not agree upon what questions should be closed, and the remainder probably choose to ignore the fact that a question should be closed. As Dan Bron mentioned, in order to avoid closing questions prematurely, it takes a consensus of five eligible voters to close a question, unless a trusted member with special privileges (such as a moderator) votes to close it. It takes time to reach such a consensus, and even if we had enough moderators to close every question which should be closed immediately, which  we do not, strictly speaking the preferred [role of a moderator](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) in Stack Exchange philosopy is that of "exception handler" for especially troublesome cases.

If a question has absolutely no value in remaining in our backlog, it may be deleted under certain conditions, at which point whether or not it was irrelevant. Closed questions are considered candidates for deletion.

As for the vote,  your answer probably was not voted against because the question was closed because if that was the case, somebody would have also voted against the other answer, which nobody did as of yet.

Presently, I have not voted against your answer, but if I may guess why somebody would do so, it was probably voted against for qualitative reasons. Here on Stack Exchange, we expect members to corraborate and explain their answers per the guidelines outlined in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).
Basically, you should corraborate your point somehow, even if it is merely with an explanation based on anecdotal evidence. You have not provided even so much as single proof of your claim or a word of explanation, and that is how your answer differs from the other answer, which at the very least least provides us some a basis for it.

Perhaps you can improve your answer by showing us that lamp and shade are antonyms in a thesaurus, or explaining which definitions of the word are opposed. I know this seems as if it should be obvious to you, since it seems as if it should be axiomatic, but everybody has to learn something a first time, and [insisting upon this](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) it is part of how we maintain the credibility and distinct usefulness of our website.

Also, votes should be assigned based upon the overall perceived usefulness of a post. If somebody thinks a question should be closed, that may just be because they do not believe it can be answered usefully, regardless of whether or not a consensus can be reached. Voting against answers you consider useless is not quite an abuse of the privilege: If you place your cursor over the voting buttons, you will see that they respectively read "This answer is useful." and "This answer is not useful."

However, some independent consideration as to whether or not they actually are useless, in spite of expectations, should probably be given. Answers are not automatically voted against when questions are voted against or closed are for a reason: The quality of each post is at least somewhat independent.